# Fail when build flutter apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, cross-platform

I update my flutter SDK, I add AndroidX, and also apply Migrating steps I can run my project without any problem. But when I try to build my project I get the error below.

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\oeu\pr\Flutter\projectname\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\oeu\pr\Flutter\projectname\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     151,5s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale tr-TR)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the Dart SDK follow these steps to build apk,
If your error says debug/libs.jar, `build --debug` then `--release`.
If your error says profile/libs.jar, `build --profile` then `--release`.
Then you can run `flutter build apk --relase` or `flutter build apk`
Highly recommend that to read this [answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247).

Answer (score 0):

From the `flutter doctor` it seems you are missing the Flutter and Dart plugin. Either it might have been deleted or, the location changed accidentally. Try reinstalling the same. Would solve the issue

Comment: Actually, that's not effects the issue I read that it is a common Android Studio bug.